# actualizar varias filas de una misma tabla

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy intentando actualizar varias filas de una tabla, de momento solo he logrado actualizar la primer fila y el resto no se actualiza.

```
foreach ($request->recibido as $key => $value) {
        $cont = Contenido::where('id_envio','=',$id)->first();
        $data = array($cont->recibido = $value);
        $cont->update($data);
    }
```

Estoy trabajando con laravel 5.5, intente cambiar el first por get() pero me dice que el metodo update no existe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que el método `first` te devuelve sólo un elemento, en cambio `get` te devuelve una [colección](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-collections) de elementos, la cual tienes que iterar para acceder a ellos.

En tu caso tu deberías hacer algo así:

```
foreach ($request->recibido as $key => $value) {
    $conts = Contenido::where('id_envio','=',$id)->get();
    // Aquí iteras la colección de contenidos y realizas una acción para cada uno de ellos
    foreach($conts as $key => $cont) {
        $data = array($cont->recibido = $value);
        $cont->update($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: ya logra actualizar todas las filas, pero se actualizan todas las filas, independientemente si selecciono o no el checkbox, en mi vista lo tengo declarado de la siguiente forma  {{Form::checkbox('recibido[]','Sí')}}

Comment: Eso ya sería otro problema, te recomendaría crear otra pregunta para esa cuestión, como que ahí cuelgas el código de tu vista ;)

Comment: ok, muchas gracias. :)